# Is it possible to change all beamer colors at once?

Tags: beamer, color

I'm working on a `beamer` theme. I know I can set colors for an element with

```
\setbeamercolor{element name}{fg=colorname}
```

Now there are a lot of possible elements, but I only need very few colors in my theme. So it would be nice to be able to overide *all* colors first with my default color an then only specify the few exceptions to my default color. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps consider switching to a different [theme](https://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/).

Comment: @Werner I'm writing a theme myself and want to keep the code clean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the beamer element colors in a beamer template are dependent on other colors. Look for example at the default color theme. Nearly all the element's colors are dependent on these four "base colors".

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=green!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
```

Also there are the four palette colors (again here the definition in the default color theme), which are kind of important.

```
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=black}
```

So if you design your own color theme you should keep that in mind. Using these "base colors" make it much easier and faster to define your own color theme.

**In short:** if you use the default color theme, changing the beamer color `structure` should already change a lot.